# Codeception moveMouseOver() has no effect on dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webdriver, codeception

I am using Codeception Webdriver to test my PHP application. I have links in a twitter bootstrap dropdown, which I want to click.

My code looks like the following:

```
$I->wantTo('Test dropdowns');
$I->moveMouseOver(['css' => 'span[class=dropdown-toggle]']);
$I->waitForElementVisible(['css' => 'ul[class=dropdown-menu]'],10);
$I->click(['link' => 'Kommentar']);
```

The corresponding HTML is:

```
<li class="border dropdown">

        <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Schreiben</span>
        <ul class="w2g_strong_shadow_and_border dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="subject"
                   onclick="showSubject('new');return false;">
                Neues Dokument</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Zum aktuellen Text einen Abschnitt hinzufügen, an dem parallel gearbeitet werden kann" class="chapter"
                   onclick="showChapter('new');return false;">
                Neues Kapitel einrichten</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a
                        href="#"
                        title = "Den aktuellen Text kommentieren"
                        onclick="showComments('new');return false;">
                    Kommentar
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Zum aktuellen Dokument – nur für Sie sichtbar" class="note"
                   onclick="W2G.showNote('new');return false;">
                Neue Notiz</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

The Framework stops at waitForElementVisible(). I am sure that I use the right selector for moveMouseOver(), because the color changes. Nevertheless, the dropdown does not appear and therefore I can't click the link.

I am testing in Firefox 44.0.2.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please give the result, on which position the test fails.

I had a similar case, where the problem was not the appearance of the dropdown, but the click on the link after:   

See http://phptest.club/t/access-dropdown-menu-in-twitter-bootstrap/806/4